# Hibernate ManyToMany with Join table problems on update

Tags: java, hibernate, orm

I am trying to make a ManyToMany association work for all CRUD operations. I have two entities : `Places` and `Events`.

Places can hold multiple events, and an events can take place in multiple places.

**In first case I had**

In class PlaceDto

```
@ManyToOne(  
    targetEntity=EventDto.class,  
    cascade = { CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE })  
@JoinTable(  
    name = "EVENTS_PLACES",  
    joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "PLACE_ID") },  
    inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "EVENT_ID") })  
private List<EventDto> events;
```

In class PlaceDto:

```
@JoinTable(name = "EVENTS_PLACES", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "EVENT_ID"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "PLACE_ID"))
private List<PlaceDto> places;
```

in this case on updating a place the link between the place and its event was erased
with `DELETE FROM EVENTS_PLACES where ...` statement

**Second case**
So after reading some docs, I changed PlaceDto to

```
@ManyToMany (
   mappedBy = "events",  
   cascade = { CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE },  
   fetch = FetchType.LAZY,  
   targetEntity = FundDto.class)  
private List<PlaceDto> places;
```

When updating a place everything seems to be fine,
but when I try to create an event, it tries also to create a place
=> which leads to a primary key violation.

I have hashcode() and equals() overridden using eclipse.

Thanks for your help.

Please do not hesitate to point me to a page where a fully working and tested ManyToMany relation is shown and explained.

Christopher

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a nice [example](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/JPA/ManyToManyJoinedTable.htm)

Just try to copy what they have there into your own code and it should work.
If it still doesn't, please post full listings for two classes and the code that causes the error and maybe I can see what the problem is.